# Google apps script quickstart tutorial not working as it should

Tags: google-apps-script

i've just started to learn programming, and i have choosed to start with Google Apps Script.
I have followed the tutorial, but for some reason the function it asks me to create simply doesn't return the expected value. I tried many different things like change some information on the code, tried to apply the same function to other cells in sheet's, but sheet's keep returning error, and i can't understand since the execution of the code doesn't return error, and the expected information about the new function created shows up when i start writing her in a cell.

Here is the code:

```
    /**
 * Calculates the sale price of a value at a given discount.
 * The sale price is formatted as US dollars.
 *
 * @param {number} input The value to discount.
 * @param {number} discount The discount to apply, such as .5 or 50%.
 * @return The sale price formatted as USD.
 * @customfunction
 */
function salePrice(input, discount) {
  let price = input - (input * discount);
  let dollarUS = Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
    style: "currency",
    currency: "USD",
});
  return dollarUS.format(price);
}
```

It then, asks me to write on cell "=salesPrice(100, .2)" , i write that and hit enter, and Sheets returns me "#ERROR" and when i try to change the values inside this statement like "=salesPrice(100, *2)" it briefly shows "loading..." but then return "$NaN".
I tried to do many other things but i keep receiving error as a result, and it was expected to work since it is just a beginner tutorial.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your locale (I guess), try

```
=salePrice(100;0,2)
```

> The function separator for each Sheet is dependent on the the country chosen from  File> Spreadsheet setting "Locale"  - For example if you choose United States then function separator is comma but if you choose France or Brazil for instance then it will be a semicolon.

Comment: This worked flawlessly, i thought the problem has to do with some regional issue, as i tried to change the value of money in sheet's to US (since i'm brazilian), but thanks for your help! Really appreciated!

Comment: Brazil use semicolon.

Comment: Accepted! I have also saved your blog for future studies, thanks!